# 502 response for sample Hello World application

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

I have created a sample hello world REST webservice using spring-boot and it works fine in local. But when I deploy the same using GCP SDK, it gets deployed succesfully on app engine and when I try to hit the url it gives 502 response

```
@RequestMapping(value="/firstapp")
    public String firstApp() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
```

Hello World! as expected response.

Comment: Usually, 502 means your code crashed. What errors do you see in Stackdriver?

Comment: Here is a [CodeLab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-app-engine-springboot/index.html?index=..%2F..spring#0) on how to make a sprig boot app in app engine, standard, you can see step by step to look for something you missed or any missed step. Also as @John mentioned, any logs on stackdriver could signal something

Comment: [Here the github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/helloworld-springboot) with java examples, in particular the helloworl springboot

Comment: @JohnHanley There is no error in Stackdriver too. https://tough-flow-248909.appspot.com/

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I have followed and used the same project. https://tough-flow-248909.appspot.com/

Comment: Did you find the answer? [This doc](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/troubleshoot-response-errors#error_code_502_or_503) says to just wait a few minutes after deploying or that app engine terminated the application because it ran out of memory, you could look into both options.